# Conducted research, can answer three 4 year old questions

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I've done some research on software while investigating a bug. That could help answering these very similar questions:

- [Odd behaviour when doing LIKE with wildcards searching for backslash in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596801/)
- [MySQL LIKE operator with wildcard and backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583144/)
- [Need to select only data that contains backslashes in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625698/)

In my opinion, none of the answers explain the root of the problem nor how to mitigate it. The closest thing that I consider to an answer is pointing out that there's [a bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583144/#8586717) which is not really helpful.

What would be *correct* course of action in this case? Should I post more or less the same answer 3 times or somehow link the answers together?

Comment: They all look like duplicates of each other. If we agree on that you pick the best q/a pair and close vote the other ones as dup of the best one. Then write an answer that does address the root cause on the dup target.

Comment: @rene are views an important metric in SO? I'd regard first question in the list as best but strangely it attracted the least views.

Comment: I personally say no, post quality is more important to me. When duped correctly it will influence views.

Comment: I guess we should treat the question that is posted first as the "best". All the others are dupes. Isn't that how duplicates work?

Comment: @Sweeper no, that's not how duplicates work.

Comment: I suggest posting the answer on all 3 questions, and closing two of them as dupes afterwards. Even when closed as a dupe, old (maybe incorrect) answers will remain, and I know that I personally don't view the dupe-link if there's a accepted answer on a question already.